# Review of my PHP Wrapper around Third Party Soap API

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes, php5, web-services

I have written a wrapper for Soap based 3rd party web service.

https://gist.github.com/veganista/bd940750d9e240e63b89

I'm pretty happy with it so far (I think, anyway).  It's only a small sub-set of what the full API offers but will suffice for my needs at the moment.

I'm looking for some criticism from some other developers on my implementation.

Edit: I'd also like some tips on how to make this easily testable. I currently haven't written any automated tests for the class. I'd use PHP Unit for testing.

```
<?php

namespace KashFlow;

class KashFlow {

/**
 * Contains the username used for authenticating with KashFlow
 * 
 * @var string $username
 */
    protected $username;

/**
 * Contains the password used for authenticating with KashFlow
 *
 * @var string $password
 */
    protected $password;

/**
 * Holds a reference to the SoapClient used by the wrapper
 *
 * @var SoapClient $client
 */
    protected $client;

/**
 * Constructor method 
 *
 * @param string $username Username used for authentication
 * @param string $password Password used for authentication
 * @return KashFlow Returns it's self
 */
    public function __construct($username, $password){
        $this->client = new \SoapClient('https://securedwebapp.com/api/service.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

/**
 * Makes a request to kashflow.
 * 
 * Used internally to for all requests but can also be used to make requests to kashflow
 * for methods without a wrapper.
 *
 * @param string $method The method to be called
 * @param array $arguments Any arguments that should be sent with the request
 */
    public function request($method, $arguments = array()){
        $arguments = array_merge(array('UserName' => $this->username, 'Password' => $this->password), $arguments);

        $result = $this->client->$method($arguments);

        if($result->Status == 'NO'){
            throw new \Exception($result->StatusDetail);
        }

        return $result;

    }

/**
 * This method returns all currencies that have been setup in the users account.
 * 
 * @link http://www.kashflow.com/developers/soap-api/GetCurrencies/
 *
 * @return array An array of objects of type Currencies
 */
    public function getCurrencies(){
        $result = $this->request('GetCurrencies');

        return $result->GetCurrenciesResult;
    }

/**
 * Gets the default currency for the account
 *
 * @return mixed Returns 
 */
    public function getDefaultCurrency(){
        $currencies = $this->getCurrencies();

        foreach($currencies as $currency){
            if($currency->isDefault){
                return $currency;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

/**
 * This method returns an array of all payments method available for use as the PayMethod
 * 
 * @link http://www.kashflow.com/developers/soap-api/GetInvPayMethods/
 * @return An array of objects of type PaymentMethod
 */
    public function getInvoicePaymentMethods(){
        $result = $this->request('GetInvPayMethods');

        return $result->GetInvPayMethodsResult->PaymentMethod;
    }

/**
 * This method will create an invoice and return the new invoice number.
 *
 * InvoiceLines are automatically added to the invoice array
 *
 * @param $data array Invoice data array
 * @param $lines array InvoiceLine data array
 * @return int An integer represeting the new Invoice number
 */
    public function insertInvoice($data, $lines = array()){
        $invoiceDefault = array(
            'InvoiceDBID' => '',
            'Paid' => 0,
            'SuppressTotal' => 0,
            'ProjectID' => '',
            'NetAmount' => 0,
            'VATAmount' => 0,
            'AmountPaid' => 0,
        );

        $lineDefault = array(
            'LineID'      => 0,
            'Quantity'    => 0,
            'Description' => '',
            'Rate'        => 0,
            'ChargeType'  => 0,
            'VatAmount'   => 0,
            'VatRate'     => 0,
            'Sort'        => 0,
            'ProductID'   => 0,
            'ProjID'      => 0,
        );

        $data = array_merge($invoiceDefault, $data, array('Lines' => array()));

        foreach($lines as $line){
            $line = array_merge($lineDefault, $line);   
            $data['Lines'][] = new \SoapVar($line, 0, 'InvoiceLine', 'KashFlow');
        }

        $result = $this->request('InsertInvoice', array('Inv' => $data));

        return $result->InsertInvoiceResult;

    }

/**
 * This method allows you to add a payment to an invoice.
 * 
 * @link http://www.kashflow.com/developers/soap-api/InsertInvoicePayment/ 
 * @param $invoiceId int ID of the invoice number to enter payment for
 * @param $data array Invoice payment data array
 * @return int An integer representing the new payment number 
 */
    public function insertInvoicePayment($invoiceId, $data = array()){
        $default = array(
            'PayID' => '',
            'PayDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'PayNote' => '',
            'PayMethod' => '',
            'PayAccount' => '',
            'PayAmount' => 0,
        );

        $data = array_merge($default, $data, array('PayInvoice' => $invoiceId));

        $result = $this->request('InsertInvoicePayment', array('InvoicePayment' => $data));

        return $result->InsertInvoicePaymentResult;
    }

/**
 * Ths method returns a customer based on their email address
 *
 * @link http://www.kashflow.com/developers/soap-api/getcustomerbyemail/
 * @param string $email Email address of the customer
 * @return mixed Returns an object of type Customer on success of false if not found
 */
    public function getCustomerByEmail($email){

        try{
            $result = $this->request('GetCustomerByEmail', array('CustomerEmail' => $email));
            return $result->GetCustomerByEmailResult;
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return false;
        }

    }

/**
 * This method lets you create a new Customer.
 * 
 * @link http://www.kashflow.com/developers/soap-api/InsertCustomer/
 * @param array An array containing cutomer data
 * @return int An integer containing the newly generated ID number for the customer
 */
    public function insertCustomer($data){
        $default = array(
            'CustomerID' => '',
            'Name' => '',
            'Contact' => '',
            'Telephone' => '',
            'Mobile' => '',
            'Email' => '',
            'Address1' => '',
            'Address2' => '',
            'Postcode' => '',
            'EC' => 0,
            'OutsideEC' => 0,
            'Source' => '',
            'Discount' => 0,
            'ShowDiscount' => false,
            'PaymentTerms' => '',
            'CheckBox1' => 0,
            'CheckBox2' => 0,
            'CheckBox3' => 0,
            'CheckBox4' => 0,
            'CheckBox5' => 0,
            'CheckBox6' => 0,
            'CheckBox7' => 0,
            'CheckBox8' => 0,
            'CheckBox9' => 0,
            'CheckBox10' => 0,
            'CheckBox11' => 0,
            'CheckBox12' => 0,
            'CheckBox13' => 0,
            'CheckBox14' => 0,
            'CheckBox15' => 0,
            'CheckBox16' => 0,
            'CheckBox17' => 0,
            'CheckBox18' => 0,
            'CheckBox19' => 0,
            'CheckBox20' => 0,
            'Created' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'Updated' => date('Y-m-d'),
        );

        $data = array_merge($default, $data);

        if(!isset($data['CurrencyID'])){
            $defaultCurrency = $this->getDefaultCurrency();
            $data['CurrencyID'] = $defaultCurrency->CurrencyId;
        }

        $result = $this->request('InsertCustomer', array('custr' => $data));

        return $result->InsertCustomerResult;
    }

/**
 * Gets a niceley formatted version of the last soap request
 *
 * @return string The last soap request
 */
    public function getLastRequest(){
        $request = $this->client->__getLastRequest();

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->preserveWhitespace = false;
        $dom->loadXml($request);

        return '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXml()) . '</pre>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips for your class:

For the lines like the following, I suggest applying different formatting (to make it more readable). Please see below:

```
$arguments = array_merge(array('UserName' => $this->username, 'Password' => $this->password), $arguments);
```

to this

```
$arguments = array_merge(
    array(
        'UserName' => $this->username, 
        'Password' => $this->password
    ), $arguments
);
```

You could just use `Exception` rather then `\Exception` is you define the class use in the beginning of your class like this:

```
use \Exception;
```

I really enjoyed your `getLastRequest()` function implementation and a trace in XML.

Comment: Yes, better readability would be an improvement there. There's nothing gained by putting it all on one line really.

I think adding the `use \Exception` and `use \SoapClient` are a good idea as it gives a bit of an overview of what the class uses.